# void pointer to template function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, void

assume this is not template function managed by me:

```
template<class T, class U>
U templatefunc(T t){ //(...); }
```

can I have a function with default arguments being template functions of type

```
templatefunc<int,double>
```

how to declare void pointer then, so I could do:

```
void _new_func( const void*=&templatefunc<int,double>)
```

I think no, because you can't have void pointer to function, it has to be function pointer, right?

previously it was:

```
void _new_func(const void* = boost::test_tools::check_is_close)
```

but with boost 1.54 it is not OK, because check_is_close is template.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a `void*` here?

Comment: I think it was on other compiler, and void pointer to function was possible, now this function became template function but I would like the _new_func remain as it was

Comment: it was: void _new_func(const void* = boost::test_tools::check_is_close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `&templatefunc<int,double>` is a pointer to function returning `double` and taking one argument of type `int`. The template arguments don't matter any more - `templatefunc<int,double>` is just the name of the (instantiated) function. So you could have:

```
void _new_func(double(*func)(int) = &templatefunc<int,double>)
```

However, it seems like you want to take functions that have varying argument and return types. In this case, you could have an overload for the case where you pass no argument:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void _new_func(U(*func)(T)) {
}

void _new_func() {
  _new_func(&templatefunc<int,double>);
}
```

Now you can call `_new_func()` and it will pass the function pointer `&templatefunc<int,double>` to the templated version. When you want to call `_new_func` with a different instantiation of `templatefunc`, you can, for example, do:

```
__new_func(&templatefunc<float, double>);
```

Comment: I can call new_func with any function taking 1 arg and returning 1 arg, right?

Answer (score 1):

A template function instantiation is a function, so anything you can do with a function you can also do with a template function instantiation. However, you can't portably store the address of a function in a `void*`, regardless of whether the function is an ordinary function or a template function instantiation.